# Почему не выводятся нужные слова?

Tags: c++, строки, char

Имеется такая задача

> В заданной последовательности слов найти все слова, имеющие заданное
>   окончание.

И мое решение:

```
    const int N = 3;
    char arr[N][20] = { "Окно", "Оно", "Двери" };
    char post[10]; //Переменная в которую записываем окончание
    int raw = 0; //Количество совпадений
    cout << "Введите окончание: "; cin >> post;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        //k - Последний символ текущего слова
        //countPost - последний символ окончания
        //countPost >= 0 - Пока не дойдем до первого символа окончаня
        for (int k = strlen(arr[i]) - 1, countPost = strlen(post) - 1; countPost >= 0; k--, countPost--) {
            if (arr[i][k] == post[countPost]) {
                //Сверяем последний символ слова с последним символом окочания, если одинаковые, то добавляем совпадения
                //Дальше сверяем предпоследние символы и так далее, пока не закончатся символы в окончании
                raw++;
            };
        };
        if (raw == strlen(post)) {
            cout << arr[i] << endl;
            //Если количество совпадений и количество символов в окончании равны, то выводим это слово
        };
        raw = 0;
    }
```

По какой-то причине ничего не выводится, где я сделал неправильно?

Comment: Странно. У меня работает. Может проблема в кириллице? (Я тестировал с латиницей)

Comment: с большой вероятностью это и есть ответ. А если ещё это все в студии/windows, то 99% и есть ответ.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, так оно и есть, а почему не работает с кириллицей?

Comment: потому что есть cp886, cp1251 и ucs-16